# How are official ruby images for Docker hub created?

Tags: ruby, docker, dockerhub

How are official ruby images on Docker hub created? And what specifically are installed inside?

Are they just a `docker build` results of one of these files in official github repo https://github.com/docker-library/ruby ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to https://hub.docker.com/_/ruby and click on any of the supported tags it will point you to the tag's Dockerfile.